# How to disable HTML email from adjusting with Dark mode?

Tags: html, html-email

I'm new to HTML codes in general. I'm trying to create an HTML email using [this template](https://github.com/leemunroe/responsive-html-email-template). Things are working fine except for one thing: the email colors are changing when my phone is on dark mode. How can I disable that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Many people desire to have their phones or computers in a dark mode/theme for readability, battery-saving, and/or reduced eye strain. You should not seek to remove this.

Furthermore, the current landscape of email clients is such that you cannot necessarily control this.

Specifically, we cannot change Outlook 2019 (Windows) or Gmail.

See the full writeup on Litmus https://litmus.com/blog/the-ultimate-guide-to-dark-mode-for-email-marketers

[image: Litmus DARK MODE TARGETING: EMAIL CLIENT SUPPORT TABLE]

Comment: You make a great point about the benefits of dark mode. And also, there is good reason to disable it: namely if you're emails aren't going to render well when dark mode is forced on for users. For example, I receive coupon emails from some retails that use transparent PNG graphics for the scannable barcode, so every time I go to checkout at the store I must now disable dark mode on my phone at the system level and go back into the app. Many vendors (retail, enterprise software, etc) are just not ready to support dark mode yet.

Comment: But that's an issue with the graphic, which is much easier to update so that doesn't happen (make it not transparent) than somehow try and disable dark mode for the entire email.

Comment: From your perspective, that may be true. But not necessarily from the perspective of the people responsible for creating the emails. Not all teams are equipped to easily make changes to their own graphics (whether custom illustrations created by an illustration team, or generated graphics like barcodes which may be sourced from an outside vendor), and for those teams being able to disable dark mode is a much simpler and friendlier solution to the accessibility problem of a forced dark mode.

Comment: Since dark mode/theme is a user system preference, that customers change on their own device, we have no control over that. It may be simpler in concept, but in practice, it's simply not possible! There are techniques, however, in graphics and code, to try and minimise the ill-effects.