# how to keep same background for email template [Newsletter] while light mode in iphone

Tags: html, css, html-email, newsletter

I want The design of the email stays exactly the same, no matter
if I view it in the dark or light email client UI:
How do I target Dark/light Mode users with my own styles?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prevent iOS 13 Dark Mode from breaking emails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58177703/how-to-prevent-ios-13-dark-mode-from-breaking-emails)

Comment: THis has been asked a few times already, e.g. .https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58177703/how-to-prevent-ios-13-dark-mode-from-breaking-emails https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60624498/how-to-disable-html-email-from-adjusting-with-dark-mode or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61657885/override-outlook-dark-mode-button-background